# How to get user along with it's computer name from active directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I am new to using Active Directory and want to create search form which take username from user, do wildcard search using that and returns username found along with it's computer name. I am using following code:

```
private SearchResultCollection GetSearchResultCollection(string DomainName, string Filter)
{
   try
   {
       /* Getting connection info. */
       Login ObjLogin = new Login();
       string ServerIP = ObjLogin.GetSystemSettingByName("LDAPServer");
       string Port = ObjLogin.GetSystemSettingByName("Port");
       string UserName = ObjLogin.GetSystemSettingByName("ADUsername");
       string Password = ObjLogin.GetSystemSettingByName("ADPassword");

       DirectoryEntry Ldap = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://" + ServerIP + ":" + Port, UserName, Password);

       DirectorySearcher LdapSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(Ldap);
       LdapSearcher.Filter = Filter;

       return LdapSearcher.FindAll();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      return null;
  }
}


public string FindUsernameInAD(string Username, out int Count)
{
    Count = 0;
    string FoundUsername = Username;

    try
    {
       /* Getting domain name */
       Login ObjLogin = new Login();
       string DomainName = ObjLogin.GetSystemSettingByName("DomainName");

       SearchResultCollection LdapSearcherResults = GetSearchResultCollection(DomainName, "(&(objectClass=user))");

       foreach (SearchResult resultLdap in LdapSearcherResults)
       {
          if ((resultLdap.Properties["sAMAccountName"] != null) && (resultLdap.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Count > 0))
          {
             if (resultLdap.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString().ToLower().Contains(Username.ToLower()))
             {
                //return resultLdap.Properties["cn"][0].ToString() + "(" + resultLdap.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString() + "@" + Username + ")";

                FoundUsername = resultLdap.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();
                Count++;
             }
          }
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       /* Catch Exception Here */
       log.Error("Error in UserManager.cs, FindUsernameInAD function: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return FoundUsername;
}
```

This code returns me username but no computer name so how do I get computer name? Also I want to know that "Is computer name for user is unique for each user in active directory?"

Comment: User and computer are two separate, independent entities - there's typically no link between the two in Active Directory.....

Comment: Thanks for reply. But is there any way by which we get it?

Comment: Unless you specifically store the user's computer in a separate, custom attribute for the user - there is **no link** between a user and a computer in AD...... you *could* of course extend the AD schema and add a new attribute to your users and then enter that information - but it's not available out of the box.

Comment: One of the primary purposes of AD is to have loose coupling between users and computers. With AD, a user can conceivably use any machine in the network.